# Goolge Play Console - update APK version for beta tests?

Tags: android

How on earth do I update my APK version during Play store beta testing? I simply see no way to upload an updated APK!

Comment: You don't. The version number is baked into the APK. If you want to submit a new version, you have to submit a new APK.

Comment: I can't even see the option to submit a new APK.

Answer (score 0):

Update `versionCode`, rebuild signed apk file, then create a new release